# SF- Separating Opportunity Stages

Tags: reporting

Issues Both Pipeline and closed Won opportunities are displayed in Field..STAGE.

1) Need to reduce Quota  by rep in a report by close-won oppty amounts

2) Then compare pipeline/(Open opptys) to the Quota to determine the amount of opptys necessary to achieve Quote.

The challenge is that this data needs be displayed in a single report.  I can't group because Pipeline and Closed won share the same field. Please Advise?

Rep: (Quota - Close-Won)= Revised Quota, (Revised Quota - Pipeline or Open Opptys) = oppty gap to Quota.

Answer (score 0):

[Look at Joined Report type](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_examples_joined.htm&language=en)

> A joined report consists of up to five report blocks, which you add to the report to create multiple views of your data. For each block, you can add regular and summary fields, create standard and cross-block custom summary formulas, apply filters, and sort columns. You apply groupings across all blocks in the report, and can add up to three groupings to the blocks, the same as for the summary format. You can also add a chart to a joined report.